# How do I know if I should pass a LocalDate vs an OffsetDateTime as a Saxon param?

Tags: java, saxon

I have an element that is defined in the XSD as:

```
<xsd:element name="publish_date" type="xsd:date"/>
```

And the query is:

```
/bks:books/book[publish_date = $p1]
```

if I call selector.setVariable(new QName("p" + (index + 1)), xdmValue); where xdmValue is an XdmAtomicValue set from a LocalDate - works great. But if I pass int an OffsetDateTime or LocalDateTime (same date component) - the query fails.

So how can I know what datetime object ype I should use to create the XdmAtomicValue. I can convert to any, but I need to know which.

Comment: Which kind of failure exactly do you get? An error? Or just not a boolean false for the `=` comparison?

Comment: First need to know which Saxon version: support for new Java date/time types became available in 10.0. Then need to know where and how it fails. If the query succeeds but finds no match then I would suspect a timezone issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are the types `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` and I think if you use `new XdmAtomicValue(someLocaleDate)` then you create an `xs:date` value while the use of `new XdmAtomicValue(someOffsetDateTime)` or `new XdmAtomicValue(someLocaleDateTime)` creates an `xs:dateTime` value.

In XPath you can't directly compare an `xs:date` value to an `xs:dateTime` with `=` or other operators, you would have to cast the `xs:date` to an `xs:dateTime` or the `xs:dateTime` to an `xs:date`, which can be done with `xs:date($p1)` on the XPath side.

So for your use of the API, if the element you want to compare to has the `xs:date` datatype, I think you want to pass in an `xs:date` value as well, meaning on the Java side you start with a LocalDate.

Comment: This might be a problem. Our customers will pass our system a datetime. The Java ones usually a Date (our code has been in use for a long time) and .Net a DateTime or DateTimeOffset. Often all they are specifying is the Date part as their data is an xs:date. But sometimes their data is an xs:datetime. Is there a way to set a parameter of LocalDateTime an it uses just the date part for an xs:date?

Comment: @DavidThielen, see the edit, I hope that works for you.

Comment: Yeah - I think we're going to have to tell our users to be careful to pass in LocalDate vs LocalDateTime. (And this is a bigger problem in C# where they don't have a LocalDate equivalent). I was hoping there was a way to say here's a LocalDateTime variable, but if it's an xs:date, please just use the LocalDate part of it (A person can dream, can't they?).

Comment: BTW - thank you for all the help on my recent questions.